# How to apply values in one column to another column in filtered data

Tags: regex, excel, excel-formula

On my Excel sheet I use filter function to see some special set of values, which includes these types:

```
"?? ??"
"?? ??"
"? ?"
"??? ??"
"? ??"
etc.
```

basically, it already filter out data that I want to process.

Now I want to replace all that values between double quotes (column C) with values in column E which is email address, but I only want to replace it with the part before @
Eg.
Column E:

```
emailname1@gmail.com
emailname2@yahoo.com
emailname3@hotmail.com
etc.
```

then column C will become:

```
"emailname1"
"emailname2"
"emailname3"
etc.
```

And how to make sure that it will not apply to the whole data on the sheet but only apply for filtered data?

Comment: The easiest solution is to use `Search and Replace`, `Find what`:`@*`, `Replace with` - leave blank.

Comment: But it is filtered data, looks like I can not paste the extracted emailnames to column C, it said that is not the same size and shape

Comment: I'm not sure, what exactly is your goal, but you can try this approach: enter `=LEFT(A2,FIND("@",A2)-1)` in the first visible row (replace `A2` with the address of email cell) and drag it down. It will fill only visible rows.

Comment: Yes, I just posted my answer and see your suggestion, just nice ! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution:
choose one cell and use the formular:

```
C180=LEFT(E180,(FIND("@",E180,1)-1))
```

Then use mouse to drag this cell to the rest of the column to use this format of formular for all the rest.
Thanks all for your contribution !